# Can't update product value after update attribute's label

Tags: magento-1.9, product, save

So, I updated the "product_length" label attribute and now I can't save a new product value to this attribute.
I can't save this value by admin or programatically.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12448);
$_product->getData('product_length'); // '195'
$_product->setData('product_length', '29');
$_product->save();
//
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12448);
$_product->getData('product_length'); // '195'
```

New products (that are created after the attribute update) works fine.

I already tried reindex all, disable and enable flat tables, clear cache (redis and files) and nothing works. There's nothing in exception.log or system.log.

Somebody help me, please! =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$product->setName('foobar!');
try {
   $product->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "{$e}";
}
```

it will display error if there any error.

Your you can use this it's works for me

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
// below code use for time format 
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution!!

When I updated the attribute's label via admin, the 'backend_type' at 'eav_attribute' mysql table changed from 'int' to 'varchar'. So I executed the query:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `backend_type` = 'int' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 177;
```

and solves the problem.

I hope this can help you too.